# Use geography functions from backend

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-core

There is a table that contains `float [Lat1], [Lon1], [Lat2], [Lon2]`. They represent coordinates of points on a map.
I need to select only those records where distance between these points is greater than some value. I also need to get the distance itself, not just coordinates.
So, in SQL I can use the following function:

```
Distance = GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat1], [Lon1], 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat2], [Lon2], 4326))
```

How do I achieve the same result using Entity Framework Core? I know I can use `.FromSqlRaw("...")` to filter records. But there seems to be no way to return calculated distance.

Comment: Use a SQL Stored procedure.

Comment: Using stored procedures like `.FromSqlRaw("stored_procedure ...")` is no different from writing sql code directly `.FromSqlRaw("select ...")`.

Comment: Why are you not getting results?  Try query in SQL Server Management Studio and see if you get results.  The SSMS give better error messages than in c#. If you are getting results in SSMS then I suspect you have to specify the full path of where the functions are located in the SQL Server.  You may be missing the system database containing the methods.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify a bit. I am getting results just fine. My entity framework model, though, has no "Distance" variable, only "Lat" and "Long". So, even if I write something like `.FromSqlRaw("select *, Distance = ... ")` I will not get the Distance value because my model does not have it.

Comment: Do you need to add the distance to the model or just get the values? When getting a list of values from a query it never make any sense to me to return one value.  How do you know what distance goes with which points.  The SQL Server is multi-threaded so doing the same query a bunch of times you will get results in a different order.  So I always recommend doing an Order By in queries.  In your case the Order By will mix up the distance and points even more.

Comment: I need to get every value from the model and distance

Comment: So don't you need ("select *, distance = equation from ......)  You can have the asterisk and additional parameters i the select query.

Comment: Yes, I can. But they will not be parsed into my model, as the model does not contain the Distance variable. I'm writing this for the 6th time.

Comment: You never answered my question : "Do you need to add the distance to the model or just get the values?"  If you need results in model than you need to add the property to the model.  Otherwise, you can just put the results of the query into a new variable.

Comment: "I need to get every value from the model and distance"

Comment: The SELECT is getting the data from the database, not the model.  Using .FromSqlRaw is doing a query in the database and return results to a c# variable (not the model).  So you can calculate the distance in the SQL Query and return the results to a c# variable.  The variable will be a two dimensional array of rows by columns.

Comment: Use a VIEW or a computed column (in the database) to calculate the Distance column.

Comment: EF Core has support for [Spatial SQL data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial), so why not use that?